# Why won't my button do the function when I click it it. It should toggle the text

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, onclick, getelementbyid

[Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMwIF.png)

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<div id="myDIV">
  This is my DIV element.
</div>
```

I found this code on W3Schools and replaced "myDIV" with "h3" so I can change the text in my header

```
    <div class="speech-buble-top"><h3 id="h3"> Happy Birthday Tiffany!</h3></div>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vRVovz - Your Code Fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue stems from you declaring the function using the `function` keyword. Usually this is fine, but I find that it's easier to work with javascript functions called by HTML as functions that have been assigned to a variable. If you use ES6 arrow syntax, you'll both be using the latest standards and binding the function to a variable. Try rewriting the function code like so:

```
<script>
  myFunction = () => {
var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
} else {
    x.style.display = "none";
   }
}
</script>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<div id="myDIV" style="display: none">
  <h3 id="h3"> Happy Birthday Tiffany!</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/oli-oli-oxen-free/pen/XExzQJ    I tried rewriting it and it's still not working D: maybe becauseI don't have all the code combined in the html file?

Comment: I just checked your codepen, I think what's happening is something is overlaying your button, since when I hover over it, I don't get the pointer cursor. I removed all the other elements from the page except for the button and tried clicking again, and it worked as expected

Comment: omg YES thank you so much I got it working now!! :D happiness I have spent like hours on this stupid thing

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: could you help me again for some reason when I resize the browser sideways the button won't move with the browser it stays put but when i resize it taller or shorter the button stays on the robots chest like it should .button{
  position:absolute;
  margin: 50px ; 
  top: 220px;
  margin-right: 150px;
  margin-left: 708px;
  left-padding: 0px;
  z-index: 1
}

Comment: Can you post a codepen so I can see what you're looking at?

Comment: omg I'm so sorry for the late reply https://codepen.io/oli-oli-oxen-free/pen/zWyRgW

Answer (score 1):

there are no script tags add the javascript tags.

> `<script type="text/javascript">    your code     </script>`

Comment: I'm using codepen so I have a JS CSS and HTML windows that are all linked together I tried adding <script><button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
              <div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div></script> and my button disappeared

Comment: read a bit more how to embed js into html... again read my answer and post the *code* and just the code, not your div....

Answer (score 0):

Your JS function must be declared **before** your button. And must be enclosed in `<script> </script>` tags

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to inline your code within the webpage then yes you will need to make sure you classify what type of code you are using. `<style></style>` is for CSS and `<script></script>` is for Javascript.

It seems like you are trying to perform a simple hide/show script. One thing that you should work on is efficiency of your code. The chunky code in your question can be shortened to this:

```js
function toggleHide() {
  var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  element.classList.toggle("hide");
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleHide()">Try it</button>
<div id="myDIV">This is a DIV element.</div>
```

Here is what it looks like inline:

```
<style>
.hide {
    display: none;
}
</style>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<div id="myDIV">This is a DIV element.</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
   var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
   element.classList.toggle("hide");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `addEventListner()` insted of inline HTML `onclick()`. Try this:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (x.style.display == "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```css
#myDIV {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="myBtn">Show</button>
<div id="myDIV" style="display: none;">Show the content</div>
```

Notice that `x.style.display` detect the inline style HTML attribute. Becouse of that, if you use a separate css file to styling the div, you'll need twice click for the first time...